# Appengine Blobstore - Video Streaming

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to setup a video streaming app via the Google Appengine Blobstore.  Just wanted to know if this was possible, as there isn't too much regarding this in the Appengine Documentation.  Basically I want to serve these videos through a flash player.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is better suited for serverfault.com

Answer (score 5):

I would say the blobstore is suitable for this. While datastore entities are limited to 1MB and standard HTTP responses are limited to 10MB, with the blobstore you can upload, store, and serve files up to 2GB. The 30 second limit refers to how long your handler can execute; time spent downloading (or uploading) doesn't count towards this limit.

The blobstore also supports byte ranges, so if your flash component supports it, you can seek to random positions in the video without downloading everything first.

Comment: Can I somehow persuade GAE to set Content-Length header, so the player would now the range it can seek?

Comment: Unfortunately not. There's a bug report on this issue @ http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4310